# Change URL of video when it is clicked ie "video.mp4" -> "video.mp4?1434"

Tags: jquery, video, video.js

I created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lz3vkwmw/4/). I want to add a time suffix to the video src of current playing video to not play the cached video. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
                strSrc = $(this).attr('src'); 
                var timestamp = new $.now();
                $(this).attr('src', strSrc + "?i=" + timestamp );
                this.player.load();
                this.player.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using video.js you'll need to use its [API](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Methodssrc) to change the source rather than trying to change a `src` attribute.

```
var timestamp = $.now(); // not `new $.now`
player.src(player.currentSrc() + "?i=" + timestamp);
```

There are a few other issues with your fiddle out of the scope of this question though and you;d need to refactor that a little. You are updating the source on every play event in an endless loop, so it would never player. Video.js has a `one()` method to listen to one instance of an event in addition to `on()`.